# Hellix3 menu won't display horizontaly stays vertical

Tags: menu, helix3

Hi guys I get have this issue with the helix menu and cant seem to straight it out. 
If I use ( nav-pills) then it takes a different style and looks bad, very bad..

Any ideas how to place the menu horizontal. (without nav-pills)

Image below.

[image: Sample of how it looks]

Answer (score 2):

you must choose menu from helix template menu option - not from module manager.

1. Go to administrator
2. Extensions/Templates/your helix template and open
3. Go to menu tab and Select Menu (your main menu)
4. Then go to menu manager and unpublish your menu module

Comment: please elaborate more on, so to create a comprehensive answer for anyone. Currently your answer although it proposes the solution, is more of a comment-like rather than a good explanatory [answer] .

Comment: edited............

Comment: Please mark answer as corect answer. thanks